# Using QGIS shapefile layer in ArcMap project?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layers

I created a QGIS shapefile layer in QGIS that I want to give to a friend of mine for his ArcMap project. Will he be able to open and use my work?

Answer (score 8):

You need to understand that there is no such thing as a `QGIS Shapefile`, A Shapefile is a shapefile regardless of what software was used to create it.

According to [ArcGIS Online Help](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/shapefiles.htm):

> A shapefile is an Esri vector data storage format for storing the location, shape, and attributes of geographic features. It is stored as a set of related files and contains one feature class.

But as [PolyGeo said](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/188718/115), you will not be able to save the symbology directly. The layer files don't work across QGIS and ArcMap directly ( maybe there is a workaround, but I'm not sure)

Answer (score 2):

If you give your friend the shapefile, and it contains a suitable *.prj, then it should be usable in ArcMap but will need to be symbolized anew. The best thing will be to perform a test transfer of data and see if it works for you.

If you are planning to share the shapefile and a layer definition file (*.qlr) to try and preserve its layer properties I would not expect the latter to be usable.

Comment: There may also be an issue with the .qpj projection file not being read by ArcGIS, and therefore a coordinate system may need to be defined (but only if the .prj is not present or does not agree with the data)